# str_replace not working - why would this be happening?

Tags: php, string

So here's my code:

```
function csq($string) 
{ 
    $search = array(chr(145), 
                    chr(146), 
                    chr(147), 
                    chr(148), 
                    chr(151),
                    chr(149),
                    "â€¢"); 

    $replace = array("'", 
                     "'", 
                     '"', 
                     '"', 
                     '-',
                     '&bull;',
                     '&bull;'); 

    return str_replace($search, $replace, $string); 
}
$username = csq($_POST["username"]);
$titletag = csq($_POST["titletag"]);
$keywordtag = csq($_POST["keywordtag"]);
$desctag = csq($_POST["desctag"]);
$content = csq($_POST["content"]);
```

As far as I can tell, each variable should take the post variable of the specified name, and then pass that to the csq() function, which will replace the special characters.

This is not happening. Am I writing something wrong?

Here's a string:

```
•   Went over key word list that was generated
o   Ant1 highlighted approved words
o   We should add a column to calculate the ratio between the number of queries vs. the number of results “in parenthesis”
```

Comment: Can you provide a `$string` that doesn't do what you intend?

Comment: in ther exemple sting there is no char in the range 140-155, so there nothing to replace

Comment: “ and the bullet should both be within the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You redifing your list each time you run the function,
   that can be avoid using static
2. to get an better overview over what translates to what i prefer using only one array
   and use array_keys to get the $search
3. are you sure you want to replace the full string "â€¢" and not each one of them separatly?

i should have writen my function like:

```
function csq($string)
{
    static $translation_table;

    if(!$translation_table)
    {
        $translation_table = array();
        $translation_table[chr(145)] = "'";
        $translation_table[chr(146)] = "'";
        $translation_table[chr(147)] = '"';
        $translation_table[chr(148)] = '"';
        $translation_table[chr(151)] = "_";
        $translation_table[chr(149)] = "&bull;";
        $translation_table["â"] = "&bull;";
        $translation_table["€"] = "&bull;";
        $translation_table["¢"] = "&bull;";
    }

    return str_replace(array_keys($translation_table), $translation_table, $string);
}
```

Comment: I believe I want to replace it all as one, not individually. It should be the same as chr(149)